# Maven assembly plugin - java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [dataload.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, executable-jar, properties-file, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to build spring boot project as an executable jar with all dpenedencies included and externalize application properties. This is how my maven assembly plugin configuration looks like:

```
    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes> 
        </resource>
    </resources>
  <plugins>     
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>                
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>       
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <archive>
          <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>          
              <mainClass>com.swift.cpms.CpmsBatchJobsStarter</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
            <Class-Path>.config/</Class-Path>
        </manifestEntries>             
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  </plugins>
</build>
```

However, I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.my.app.BatchJobsStarter]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [dataload.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>           at com.my.app.BatchJobsStarter.main(BatchJobsStarter.java:38)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [dataload.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>           at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
>           at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:154)
>           at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
>           at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:72)
>           at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:58)
>           at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.(ResourcePropertySource.java:65)
>           at org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(DefaultPropertySourceFactory.java:36)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:440)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:271)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:190)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:292)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
>           ... 10 common frames omitted

First question: Why it is complaining about the properties file by name if I exclude it?

Second question: Where do I need to place it for jar to find it during execution? I tried to place my property files outside the jar in the same directory, in /lib or /config changing class-path in manifestEntries accordetnly (where I want them to be). I tried to put them even inside the jar, but I still get exactly the same result.

Can anyone point me, what exactly am I doing wrong in this case? Thank you